# Cosa sono "i lugagni"?

Tags: meaning

Questo brano appartiene a *La Locandiera* di Carlo Goldoni (il corsivo è mio):

> DEJANIRA: Verranno i nostri compagni, e subito ci sbianchiranno.
>
> ORTENSIA: Per oggi non possono arrivare a Firenze. Da Pisa a qui in navicello vi vogliono almeno tre
>   giorni.
>
> DEJANIRA: Guardate che bestialità! Venire in navicello!
>
> ORTENSIA: *Per mancanza di lugagni*. È assai che siamo venute noi in calesse.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "per mancanza di lugagni". Ho cercato il vocabolo "lugagno", ma non l'ho trovato in nessun dizionario in rete. Curiosamente però questa stessa espressione appare anche
in [questo sito web](http://notizie.comuni-italiani.it/foto/65145). Dopo aver letto questo testo, ho pensato che "per mancanza di lugagni" forse significasse "per mancanza di soldi". È così? Si tratta di un'espressione di uso regionale? "I lugagni" erano una moneta usata nel passato in qualche parte d'Italia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sì, con  ***[lugagni](https://renatomastro1954.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/la-locandiera.pdf)*** si intendevano ***denari*** nel gergo dei commedianti:

> - 74)  ***lugagni***:denari (sempre gergo dei commedianti: Goldoni che lo conosceva bene data la sua pratica del teatro, si compiace a riprodurlo con fedeltà.)

Comment: Grazie mille! È molto interessante questo link!